# Reading file system Windows apache cordova app

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I am using the cordova-file plugin to read a file I have stored in my app and load it for the user to view.

I have the following code:

```
function readFileName(identifier) {
        var ret = ""
        var directory = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/presentations/files/";
        var fileName = identifier.getAttribute("data-link")
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(directory, function (directoryEntry) {
            directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                ret = fileEntry.nativeURL;
            }, ret = null);
        }, fail);
        return ret;
    }
```

directory resolves as ms-appx:///www/presentations/files/

The code works fine in Android, but in a Windows App, it returns an error code of 5 which according to the docs is ENCODING_ERR.

I'm assuming it's because the path to my file is incorrect, but the docs say that ApplicationStorage works on Windows 10 and haven't found anything to suggest that the www/presentations/files/ folder doesn't exist (It certainly exists in my deug folder).

I'm pretty stuck as to work out how to resolve. Even when I try to resolve the root directory like so:

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(directory, function (directoryEntry) {
            var reader = directoryEntry.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(function success(entries) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

                    console.log('En - ', entries[i].fileName);
                }
            }, fail);
```

I still get the same error. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I have looked at the following bug

https://github.com/Reon90/cordova-plugin-file/blob/a4df917e66d0c35cb3e11ca3257f54b8b7dd3eab/src/windows/FileProxy.js

I have applied the change to the file but am still getting the same error

Comment: Does it work if you add `<preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx://" />` to config.xml and rebuild?

Comment: Sadly not, still same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have looked at the following bug
>   https://github.com/Reon90/cordova-plugin-file/blob/a4df917e66d0c35cb3e11ca3257f54b8b7dd3eab/src/windows/FileProxy.js
>   I have applied the change to the file but am still getting the same error

I made a demo and tried fixing it with the codes from this link. It didn't work at first. But after I removed the windows platform using Command `cordova platform rm windows` and run the application again. It works!

Notes: For details about what has been made to fix the problem please refer to [Changes made to FileProxy.js](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/pull/193/commits/a4df917e66d0c35cb3e11ca3257f54b8b7dd3eab).

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible to execute `platform rm windows` from VS. Please use [Cordova Command Line Tool](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/index.html) instead. If you haven't installed CLI, please follow the steps of [Install cordova CLI](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html#installing-the-cordova-cli).

Comment: Thanks, yeah did a quick google and did it from a node js window, seems to have worked so thanks!